# Can I use CASE statement with a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

I have 2 tables with values:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
   ids int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   surname varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE register (
   idr int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   data_ora datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   idstu int DEFAULT NULL,
   grade int DEFAULT NULL,
   INDEX idstu (idstu),
);
```

And the request is: the list of students' grades in 2015, depending on the average (10, 9 - Very good, 8,7 - Good, 6,5 - satisfactorily, 4-0 - not good)

I would like to use the CASE statement but I don't know how to use it with a JOIN statement.

I tried this:

```
SELECT name, surname, ROUND(avg(nota),2) as average
JOIN register ON students.ids = register.idstu,
CASE average
WHEN 10 THEN 'Very good'
WHEN 9 THEN 'Very good'
WHEN 8 THEN 'Good'
WHEN 7 THEN 'Good'
WHEN 6 THEN 'satisfactorily'
WHEN 5 THEN 'satisfactorily'
ELSE 'Not good'
END AS mark
FROM students
WHERE YEAR(data_ora) = 2015;
```

But I get an error - unknown column 'average' in the field list.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot reference a column alias in the same select list. You will need to use a derived table.

Comment: You are shaky on joins too. I suggest you get the joins sorted before worrying about the presentation.

Comment: `SELECT CASE ... FROM (SELECT ... JOIN ...)`?

Comment: I personally would just return the data and leave presentation (i.e. conversion to strings) to the application anyway... Assuming C or C++ you could store the strings in an array and use the grade as index into it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your query order is not correct. The correct query should look alike -

```
SELECT name, surname, CASE WHEN ROUND(avg(nota),2) >= 9 THEN 'Very good'
                           WHEN ROUND(avg(nota),2) >= 7 THEN 'good' 
                           WHEN ROUND(avg(nota),2) >= 5 THEN 'satisfactorily'
                           ELSE 'Not good' END AS mark
  FROM students
  JOIN register ON students.ids = register.idstu
 WHERE YEAR(data_ora) = 2015
 GROUP BY name, surname;
```

Comment: @LucicaSavin, Always welcome.